# Передать setText в другое Activity

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Есть Activity "A" в котором есть setText. в этот setText передаются данные. Как мне из Activity "A" передать setText в Activity "B"?

Comment: Метод между активити не передать. А вот сами данные можно. Положите их в интент запуска активити)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052063/4711135

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я так пробовал. Почему-то передается null.

Comment: @Samoilov, значит как-то не так делали. Покажите как данные записывали и как считывали - возможно сможем сказать что не так